# How to build numpy from source and be able to debug it in a live application?

Tags: numpy, open-source

I am currently reading the documentation for numpy, however to get a more thorough understanding of the library, it would be helpful if there was a way to debug the workflow of the library as I call a particular function.

I have tried debugging when numpy was imported as a third party module. However, when I try to step into it, it is actually stepping over.

Therefore, I am building it from source and thereby trying to build it locally in an attempt to run it.

I find the documentation provided in the numpy website for developers to be a bit vague for beginners like me.

I would highly appreciate any comments that would set me on the right path, as I have tried everything that I know of.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you already comfortable using `numpy` as described the `essentials` documentation?  Able to predict what `np,array` returns in most cases?  Index in various ways?  Read function code when it's written in python? Studying the C source code should follow those skills, not precede them.

Comment: There's nothing specific to Git, ML, or AI in numpy: it's just code to do numerical work. You will need to know how to use C, Python, and the intersection between those two; and you will need to know a lot about numerical methods and floating-point, if you're going to work on numpy itself.

Answer (score 1):

> I am currently reading the documentation for numpy, however to get a more thorough understanding of the library, it would be helpful if there was a way to debug the workflow of the library as I call a particular function.

Unless you plan to fix a bug in Numpy, help Numpy developpers or you are a contributor, you should not debug Numpy directly.

> I have tried debugging when numpy was imported as a third party module. However, when I try to step into it, it is actually stepping over.

By default, Numpy enable *compiler optimizations* like `-O2` or `-O3` or even using annotations in the code so to tell the compiler to use a given optimization level (so to better vectorize it for example). Such optimizations tends to make debugging harder and unreliable. The maximal optimization level for debugging should be `-Og` and the minimal one is `-O0`. Using `-O1`/`-O2`/`-O3` tends to causes issues. You also need to enable debugging informations with `-g`.

The standard way to run and debug Numpy is to use `gdb --args python runtests.py -g --python mytest.py`. The `-g` flag should compile Numpy with compiling options `-O0 -ggdb`. Adding `--debug-info` may help you to understand if everything is built correctly. For more information see [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/dev/development_environment.html#debugging) and [that](https://numpy.org/devdocs/dev/development_advanced_debugging.html). You can also see the above informations in the [runtests.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/runtests.py) script.

If you still have issues with the above method, the last desperate option is to add `printf` directly in the code (and take care to flush stdout frequently). It is not very clean and force Numpy to be frequently recompiled which is a bit slow but it is a pretty good solution when gdb is unstable (ie. crashes or just bogus) for example.

Thank you for contributing to Numpy.